# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, git, go-cd

Using GOCD pipeline. We have two nodes, one of which clones code fine, this older node does not. We are seeing Cannot run program "git": error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable in the logs. Is there some configuration I am able to check?

Logs:

```
020-08-25 17:39:18,629 [loopThread] ERROR thoughtworks.go.work.DefaultGoPublisher:135 - Error while executing [git clone --branch=20.08_OMS_15.09_Endpoint git@github.comcast.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git /app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build] 
 Make sure this command can execute manually.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while executing [git clone --branch=20.08_OMS_15.09_Endpoint git@example.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git /app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build] 
 Make sure this command can execute manually.
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.ExceptionUtils.bomb(ExceptionUtils.java:36)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.config.materials.git.GitMaterial.updateTo(GitMaterial.java:159)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.domain.MaterialRevision.updateTo(MaterialRevision.java:151)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.domain.materials.AbstractMaterialAgent.prepare(AbstractMaterialAgent.java:41)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.remote.work.BuildWork.prepareJob(BuildWork.java:193)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.remote.work.BuildWork.build(BuildWork.java:141)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.remote.work.BuildWork.doWork(BuildWork.java:96)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.agent.JobRunner.run(JobRunner.java:60)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.agent.AgentHTTPClientController.retrieveWork(AgentHTTPClientController.java:123)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.agent.AgentHTTPClientController.work(AgentHTTPClientController.java:99)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.agent.AgentController.loop(AgentController.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.MethodInvokingRunnable.run(MethodInvokingRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.timer.DelegatingTimerTask.run(DelegatingTimerTask.java:70)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.go.util.command.CommandLineException: Error while executing [git clone --branch=20.08_OMS_15.09_Endpoint git@example.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git /app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build] 
 Make sure this command can execute manually.
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:112)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.ProcessManager.createProcess(ProcessManager.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.command.CommandLine.createProcess(CommandLine.java:361)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.command.CommandLine.execute(CommandLine.java:354)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.command.CommandLine.run(CommandLine.java:513)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.domain.materials.SCMCommand.run(SCMCommand.java:34)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.domain.materials.git.GitCommand.clone(GitCommand.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.config.materials.git.GitMaterial.git(GitMaterial.java:247)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.config.materials.git.GitMaterial.updateTo(GitMaterial.java:153)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git": error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.thoughtworks.go.util.ProcessManager.startProcess(ProcessManager.java:105)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=11, Resource temporarily unavailable
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

GO CD Build:

```
20:21:26.207 [go] Job Started: 2020-08-25 20:21:26 UTC

20:21:26.207 [go] Start to prepare PATGUI-build/131/Execute_Script/1/build_job on exmaple-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent3]
20:21:26.212 [go] Start to update materials.

20:21:26.212 [go] Start updating files at revision 1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2 from git@github.comcast.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git
20:21:26.214 Error while executing [git clone --branch=20.08_OMS_15.09_Endpoint git@example.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git /app/go-agent3/pipelines/PATGUI-build] 
 Make sure this command can execute manually.
20:21:26.231 [go] Job completed PATGUI-build/131/Execute_Script/1/build_job on exmaple-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent3]
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by restarting the go agent. A new issue arouse but this issue was resolved by the following.

1. Login into GoCD UI.
2. Click on "Agents"
3. Select the agent which is required to be restarted
4. click on Disable button
5. refresh the page.
6. You will see that agent disabled and at the last in the list
7. Copy the "Agent Name". This is the host of agent. Login into this host with Cada credentials.
8. Run command : sudo su -
9. Now execute : sudo /etc/init.d/go-agent1 restart (Note : The last digit after agent will change as per Agents/"sandbox" value in the GoCD UI)
   Above command will restart the agent
10. Now go back to the GoCD UI, select the disabled agent and click on Enable.
11. Refresh the page, agent should be back in idle state.Restarting GoCD agents: